# Как задать параметры для команды discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

я хочу сделать команду которая будет отправляться в определённый канал.
К примеру команда test выводится эмбед Текст который напишу в дискорде(заголовок) Текст который напишу в дискорде(другой)(дополнение) Текст который напишу в дискорде(другой1)(текст).
Возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

если не ошибаюсь, то код должен быть таким:

```
@client или bot.command()
async def test(ctx, name,*, text):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = f'{name}', description=f"{text}"
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)
```

реализацию с дополнениями не смог сделать